# Spreadsheet Formula read the wrong Value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, vlookup, spreadsheet

I run the Vlookup Formula with data like this in he Spreadsheet:

```
A65     B65    C65         D65             E65            F65             G65
AGR     1      1       Penjualan      12/12/2022       Makanan       15,500
```

I used formula :

```
=IFNA(Vlookup(A65,A:D,4,0),"")
```

should returns the value as "Penjualan" or "" if nothing.

but it returns other value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your formula is correct unless there is one more AGR in range A1:A64. try:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A65, A65:D65, 4, 0))
```

to see that its working properly

Comment: Thanks. and there is another AGR. im wrong using A:D in the formula. thank you so much